# Excel 2010 - Vertical alignment of text simply not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, alignment

I have a long, multiple line-break-separated (Alt+Enter) text in a cell, and I would like to set its height to a specific number, but still see the most recent note I made (going from top to bottom), thus I will need the cell's vertical alignment to be set to Bottom, however, if I click any of the vertical alignment buttons (or do this in the Format Cell > Alignment window), nothing happens, truly nothing. I mean, it moves just about a pixel or so, but it does not do the alignment, it remains Top aligned. The cell type is set to Text, so that could not be an issue.

Anything you guys can think of this could be caused by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue. See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169101

> This problem occurs if the cell is not large enough to display all of
>   the text it contains.

Text will not bottom-align unless the cell is high enough to show all text. Kind of defeats the purpose of bottom align and it is not a solution to your question, just an explanation.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I didn't see that article, thanks a lot! What a pity, Microsoft...